# Find out which raster has highest values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I have 3 rasters for water use and 1 raster for water supply.

I want to know which one has the highest values which will mean that it has the greatest influence on available water supply.

What tools can I use for this in arcmap 10.0 and how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The tool is called [cell statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm).

the statistics type you want is MAXIMUM.

If you only want a value where they all overlap set the environment setting ([Output Extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000)) to intersect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I ran the cell statistics but it I don't understand the output. I actually want to know which of the rasters out of the three has the highest values in general over the others. Like a table of this information.

Comment: Use Highest Position from Spatial Analyst - Local

Comment: Thanks FelixIP I tried to run the Highest Position but got an error.

Comment: Try shorter names and output to grid not database raster

Comment: FelixIP I have been able to run it and got a raster grid with 1, 2 and 4 label but I don't know how to interpret this. I was hoping for a sort of ranking of the raster inputs by name or as a table. Ranking by which raster has the higher cell values.

Comment: 1=Livestock, 2= Irrigation, etc. Numbers=order in which you've placed grids in a tool window. Thus you can open attribute table of output. add field 'whatever' and assign names, using field calculator

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking now. Sum total of all values in a raster vs. sum of all values in another raster OR highest value of each pixel in Raster 1 vs. Highest value of each pixel in Raster 2

Comment: highest value of each pixel in Raster 1 vs. Highest value of each pixel in Raster 2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Highest Position](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/highest-position.htm) tool.

> Determines on a cell-by-cell basis the position of the raster with the maximum value in a set of rasters.

[image]