# Selecting max values from list of raster layer and attaching raster source of max value using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, statistics

[image]

I have three raster layers (a,b,c) and I am wondering if I can extract the maximum values AND attach the limiting raster(s) that contribute to the maximum value as illustrated. What I can do so far is only obtain the maximum values using Cell Statistics, but I have no idea which raster(s) make the maximum values of the output (symbolised as alphabets in the illustration).

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Comment: Have you looked at Combine tool: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combining-multiple-rasters.htm?

Comment: Highest Position https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/124034/2856